# Using a variable as both an integer and a string (Python)

Tags: python

I would like to use a variable as an integer and a string in the same statement. In BASIC, it would look like this:

```
cnt = 0

while cnt < 10:
    cnt = cnt + 1
    print cnt + " + 1 = " + cnt + 1
```

I understand it's a bit different with Python (integers have to be converted before you print them as strings, but here using a function such as "cnt = str(cnt)" doesn't seem to work very well). What would be the easy way to do this?

Comment: When you say "BASIC", which variant do you mean? There are a lot of different ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cnt = 0

while cnt < 10:
    print str(cnt) + " + 1 = " + str(cnt + 1)
    cnt = cnt + 1
```

or

```
for cnt in range(10):
    print str(cnt) + " + 1 = " + str(cnt + 1)
```

or

```
for cnt in range(10):
    print "%d + 1 = %d".format(cnt, cnt + 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one, since Python is [**strongly typed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing).

```
print '%d + 1 = %d' % (cnt, cnt + 1)
```

Comment: Use of the `%` operator in this way is discouraged (possibly deprecated). Users of newer versions of Python (2.6+) should favour the `format` method.

Comment: It, however, is what people are used to and continues to work through 3.2+.

Comment: @Marcelo, I don't think it's deprecated yet. `.format()` doesn't work on Python <2.6 (including google app engine). I agree that it is preferred, but I'd still use format strings if the version isn't specified as many people are still using 2.5 and even 2.4

Comment: @agf: I agree that's what they're used to (and indeed must use if they are on older versions), but we should still encourage use of modern idioms where practicable.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 2.6+, the `format` method is the preferred way to build up strings containing other values:

```
'{0} + 1 = {1}'.format(cnt, cnt + 1)
```

Comment: +1, but you should mention that Python2.6+ is required for this answer

Answer (score 3):

You had it nearly right; you just need to tell Python exactly when to make something a string.

```
>>> cnt = 0
>>> while cnt < 10:
...     cnt += 1
...     print str(cnt) + " + 1 = " + str(cnt + 1)
... 
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 1 = 4
4 + 1 = 5
5 + 1 = 6
6 + 1 = 7
7 + 1 = 8
8 + 1 = 9
9 + 1 = 10
10 + 1 = 11
```

Strictly speaking, you aren't treating `cnt` as both an integer and a string here -- it's always an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
print str(cnt) + " + 1 = " + str(cnt + 1)
```

or

```
print "%d + 1 = %d" % (cnt, cnt+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print `int`s as well as `str`ings.  You may be confused by some of the answers if you know that it is quite possible to write `print cnt` on its own, without explicitly putting it into a string.

The string formatting language is useful and powerful and something you do need to know about.  But it's perfectly fine to write

```
print cnt, "+ 1 =", cnt + 1
```

which is closer in spirit to what you asked.  Python automatically adds spaces between the arguments, and a newline character at the end of the line (to suppress this, add another comma at the end).